# PHP GD library, turn 2 images into 1 side by side

Tags: php, image, gd

I want to take two images and turn them into one side by side (not overlapping). An example of what I'd want to do is something like a before and after picture (both images would have the same height with a different width). Any example code on how to accomplish with with the PHP GD image library would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php

$img1_path = 'images_1.png';
$img2_path = 'images_2.png';

list($img1_width, $img1_height) = getimagesize($img1_path);
list($img2_width, $img2_height) = getimagesize($img2_path);

$merged_width  = $img1_width + $img2_width;
//get highest
$merged_height = $img1_height > $img2_height ? $img1_height : $img2_height;

$merged_image = imagecreatetruecolor($merged_width, $merged_height);

imagealphablending($merged_image, false);
imagesavealpha($merged_image, true);

$img1 = imagecreatefrompng($img1_path);
$img2 = imagecreatefrompng($img2_path);

imagecopy($merged_image, $img1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img1_width, $img1_height);
//place at right side of $img1
imagecopy($merged_image, $img2, $img1_width, 0, 0, 0, $img2_width, $img2_height);

//save file or output to broswer
$SAVE_AS_FILE = TRUE;
if( $SAVE_AS_FILE ){
    $save_path = "your target path";
    imagepng($merged_image,$save_path);
}else{
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($merged_image);
}

//release memory
imagedestroy($merged_image);

?>
```

try it

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly Parfait! How can I then upload the merged image to the server? I tried `move_uploaded_file` and `copy`, but neither worked.

Comment: Thanks but that's actually not working. When I run the script it shows an empty image and doesn't write anything to the folder. Also, I have the permissions for the folder set to 777 and am using two .png images.

Comment: what is the result of imagepng($merged_image), is it empty or throws other errors?

Comment: It just shows an empty image (same as if you specified a non-existent image path in an `<img src="non-existent.png" />` tag). No errors are displayed. The other script worked perfectly. Only the one where it tries to upload the image doesn't work for me.

Comment: try var_dump( imagepng($merged_image,$save_path) ); , is it return true?